# Visual Studio's IntelliSense disabled error squiggles and I can't turn them back on

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

When I go to "Disable Squiggles" in Tools->Options->C/C++->Advanced->IntelliSense the value is set to true and greyed out. It won't let me change the setting. You can see what I mean in the image here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGODz.png

I recently installed the extension Viasfora. Could that extension be causing this? If not, what?

Comment: Set "Disable error reporting" back to False.

Comment: oh... thank you. That's a pretty obvious one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.